# insert ng-click in append statment angular js

Tags: angularjs

```
  for(var i = 0 ; i<data.success.length; i++)
            {
              // console.log(data.success[i]);

                  $("#show_rules").append("<li style='display: flex;'><div class='checkbox' id='container_divv'><a id='mm'ng-click='edit_initial_infoq()' >"+data.success[i].name+"</a><button ng-click='edit_initial_infoq()'>dd</button></div></li>");


            }
            })

            };
                         $scope.edit_initial_infoq= function(){
                         console.log('edit_initial_infoq');
                             };
```

it's not giving me error and cant process the edit_initial_infoq function

Comment: Its hard to tell exactly what is going on with the limited code segment you included.   In this inside of a controller or directive?   Can you provide a bit more context in regards to the code around it.

Comment: it's the controller i'm appending the li  including <a> with ng-click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you're appending to the html and angular isn't aware of the changes and therefore the ng-click isn't working.   Try the following:

**Instead of:**

```
var html = "<li style='display: flex;'><div class='checkbox' id='container_divv'><a id='mm' ng-click='edit_initial_infoq()'>"+data.success[i].name+"</a><button ng-click='edit_initial_infoq()'>dd</button></div></li>";
#("#show_rules").append(html);
```

**Try doing:**

```
var html = "<li style='display: flex;'><div class='checkbox' id='container_divv'><a id='mm' ng-click='edit_initial_infoq()'>"+data.success[i].name+"</a><button ng-click='edit_initial_infoq()'>dd</button></div></li>";
var myElement = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#show_rules' ) );
myElement.append( $compile(html)($scope) );
```

HOWEVER... you shouldn't do this.  You shouldn't manipulate the DOM inside of a controller as you're doing.  Instead, try doing the following:

**JavaScript**:

```
YourService.loadRules().then(function(data){
    $scope.rules = data.success;
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<ul id="show_rules">
    <li ng-repeat="rule in rules" style='display: flex;'>
        <div class='checkbox' id='container_divv'>
            <a id='mm' ng-click='edit_initial_infoq()'>
                {{rule.name}}
            </a>
            <button ng-click='edit_initial_infoq()'>dd</button>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a great SO question to read, the first answer is loaded with great information: ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)